# Auto fire Query and send mail in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do php code for send mail automatically

suppose my database table table contain user information and their birth date and i want to

send then mail automatically at their birth date .

I dont know how to fire query at every new day and fetch data from database and send user mail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to set cron jobs which are used to automatically execute a certain script at your specified time on recurring basis. Let's say you want to execute a script on daily basis then you will set the cron duration to 1 day.

Read more about Cron Jobs here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

A basic example of how you can do it on bluehost is as follows.

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/cron

First of all write a script in php which whenever runs, will query the database and fetch all those user's records which have birthdays today.

Then, try to run that script and see if it works as expected.

After this, when you create a cron job using your server, you will assign this php file to run on daily basis at your specified time. So, whenever once this script runs, it will query the database using today's date and hence this process will go on.

Let me know if you still have any confusion.

Comment: thanks and i will go throw that tutorial . and suppose i get data via jQuery but how i assign that data to PHP veriable ????? because we can assign PHP variable data to jQyuery but we are not assign jQuery data to PHP . I have to assign this data  via class or id when those data fetch M I right ?? @basit

Comment: you can assign server data to client but not the client data back to server. Server here is php and client is jQuery. What you're trying to do needs an ajax call using jQuery which will send your data back to server and you can do whatever you want to do with it there.

Comment: @Affan why do you expect that you will use jquery in this situation? This does not make any sense.

Comment: so how i have to call query at every day ????? #t.niese

Comment: @Affan Please don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted if it answers your question.

Comment: @Affan as this answer tells you you have to use _cron jobs_. A _cron job_ will call your script in defined intervals. Did you ever bother to follow and read the links?